# The Jlabel component disappeared from my Netbeans's palette

Tags: netbeans, jlabel, palette

I've been working on netbeans, coding some Java, and while designin a Jframe, I can't find the JLabel component on my Palette:

image : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/524059label.png

Where can I get it back please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click on the header **Swing Controls** in your palette
2. Select **Properties**
3. In the Dialog, open the tree node **Swing Controls**
4. Select the **Label** check box
5. Close

Comment: Sorry, I'm new round here

Answer (score 3):

In my version of Netbeans 7.4 you do this instead:

1. Right-click on the header Swing Controls in your palette
2. Select Reset