# The JButton component disappeared from my Netbeans's palette

Tags: netbeans

I can't find the JButton component on my Netbean Palette:

[image]

[image]

Where can I get it back please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Jlabel component disappeared from my Netbeans's palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342553/the-jlabel-component-disappeared-from-my-netbeanss-palette)

Comment: The process of fixing it is the same as in the link above for JLabel.

Comment: It seems that you delete it you can solve your problem like :

    `right Click in the palleter > Reset Palete`

Comment: Yeah! This is useful. Thank you!